# cmake qt5_generate_repc() places rep header in CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qtremoteobjects

I'm trying to determine the right way to build my project. Due to requirements I'm using cmake instead of qmake. In my Qt project I'm using *Remote Objects*.

The problem is that `qt5_generate_repc` generates my header from the `.rep` file and places it in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and to make it accessible for include I need to `target_include_directories` my build directory and I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Maybe there is a better way or I don't understand some fundamentals?

Comment: Including the binary directory in your include path is a perfectly normal, accepted practice. It lets you isolate the build artifacts (i.e. the .rep file header) from your sources.

Comment: You're welcome! I just turned my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that `qt5_generate_repc` that generates me header from .rep file places it in the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and to make it accessible for include I need to target_include_directories my build directory and I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

That is a perfectly normal and accepted practice and indeed is the *best thing to do* for build-time generated sources. You should do this.

The simple reason is that you should never write to the source directory in an out-of-tree build, which is the blessed way to use CMake (out-of-tree).

The overall effect is to prevent a class of name clashing and overwriting issues that might occur.